# MATLAB Convert cell to double and concatenate or reshape into one column

Tags: matlab, concatenation, cell, mat

I have lat and lon as cells of size 1x7 (in which inside each cell, the cell is a column with varying numbers of rows). I want to convert each of the 7 columns to double and then concatenate them into a column so that I have a matrix of size 216x1.

For example (shortened version), if

```
 lat{1,1}
'40.400959'
'40.695078'
'40.969112'
'41.264171'
'41.400968'
'41.517772'
'41.530011'
'41.550005'
'41.583183'
'41.603159'

 lat{1,2}
'38.082155'
'38.176278'
'38.529631'
'38.612034'
'38.700632'
```

Then, I want to have, in double form:
    40.400959
    40.695078
    40.969112
    41.264171
    41.400968
    41.517772
    41.530011
    41.550005
    41.583183
    41.603159
    38.082155
    38.176278
    38.529631
    38.612034
    38.700632

I managed to convert to double, but I'm not sure how to do the concatenate (or reshape) to column part.

```
for i = 1:7
    lat = str2double(lat_PM25{i});
    lon = str2double(lon_PM25{i});
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
str2double(vertcat(lat{:}))
```

*How this works*:

`lat{:}` gives you a comma-separated list of the cell contents. Each cell content is in turn a single-column cell-array of strings (I assume).

`vertcat` concatenates all those single-column cell-arrays of strings into one single-column cell-array of strings.

`str2double` converts each string into a `double` number and packs all those numbers into a column vector.

*Example*:

```
lat{1,1} = {
'40.400959'
'40.695078'
'40.969112'
'41.264171'
'41.400968'
'41.517772'
'41.530011'
'41.550005'
'41.583183'
'41.603159'};

lat{1,2} = {
'38.082155'
'38.176278'
'38.529631'
'38.612034'
'38.700632'};
```

gives

```
ans =
   40.4010
   40.6951
   40.9691
   41.2642
   41.4010
   41.5178
   41.5300
   41.5500
   41.5832
   41.6032
   38.0822
   38.1763
   38.5296
   38.6120
   38.7006
```

Comment: I bow, I bow, and here goes my answer.